# Nuance of "behelligen"

Tags: word-choice, verb, difference

I am trying to grasp the nuances of *behelligen*, which I understand to mean something along the lines of "bother".

For example, when trying to express

> I am very sorry to bother you once more with this matter

the verbs *nerven*, *stören*, *belästigen*, etc. feel too strong, so I wonder if *behelligen* might be a better match:

> Es tut mir sehr leid, Sie diesbezüglich nochmals zu behelligen

Is this correct, or have I misunderstood how to use *behelligen*?

In which other contexts can one use *behelligen*? Does it have a formal ring to it, or is it also used in daily conversation?

Comment: It's almost perfect. It must be "… leid, …" There is a noun *das Leid*, but here it's the adjective *leid* of the verb phrase *leid tun*. Also, there has to be a comma because an infinitive clause follows.

Comment: @Janka Thank you, good to know! Apparently the [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/leidtun) lists the verb as *leidtun*, giving *es tut mir leid* and *leid* just being a separable prefix...? Never ever learned punctuation ^^'

Comment: These separated and conjoined verbs phrases are often alternatives just from the fact one variant was common before the 1996 spelling reform and one after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You correctly understood the meaning of *behelligen*.
It can be used in daily conversation, but in this case *diesbezüglich* would be replaced by *damit*. When you start your sentence with *Es tut mir leid*, then I'd always add *zu müssen* for stylistic reasons:

> Es tut mir leid, Sie damit noch mal behelligen zu müssen.

Answer (score 1):

> > Es tut mir sehr leid Sie diesbezüglich nochmals zu behelligen
>
> Is this correct, or have I misunderstood how to use behelligen?

*"Behelligen"* literally means to bother someone, thus an excuse coming along with it is good practice.

This is perfectly fine and even polite.

The apology expressed with *"Es tut mir sehr leid"* also is well placed and expresses politenes and shows compassion for the subject addressed.